# python 3.2: cx_freeze does not import all of pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial, cx-freeze

I am having issues building an exe verision of my python 3.2 script. The script requires pyserial and builds using cx_freeze. However, when I run the exe I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27,
in   <module>
  exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "my_serial_program.py", line 1, in <module>
  import serial
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  from .serialwin32  import *
File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 12, in <module>
  from . import win32
ImportError: cannot import name win32
```

Doing a little snooping, Pyserial site-package has a "win32.py" module (in addition to serialwin32.py); however, in the compressed lib that cx_freeze produces, win32.py is missing. Simply placing a pyc version does not fix the issue. Also using cx_freeze "includes = [ ]" does not work.

Any ideas? Is my question even cogent (I am fairly new to python)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There is an option to include extra modules as mentioned in [cx_Freeze ImportError: cannot import name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223128/cx-freeze-importerror-cannot-import-name) and [documentation for cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html)

Just append `--include-modules serial.win32`